# Inherting parent folder permissions in new java-created files

Tags: java, linux

I hava a java application, that creates files and folders somewhere on the customer machines.
i need that the new files and folders will get the same permissions as their parent folder, and their same permitted group.

I can tell the user to do some linux manipulations on the parent folder (like using umask), but i cannot tell him to change some files that effect on all his machines....

how can i do that?

Comment: Are you able to use Java 7?  If so, have a look at the [java.nio.file](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: @prunge And what is the solution with Java 7?